# ARM template array parameter

Tags: arrays, azure, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM template with a web app alerting rule, where I want to be able to configure which e-mails get the alerts.

The snippet for the e-mail alerting action is this:

```
"action": {
    "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
    "sendToServiceOwners": false,
    "customEmails": [
        "email1@example.com",
        "email2@example.com"
    ]
}
```

The same template is used for setting up production, test, and dev environments. So I would like to use a parameter for the e-mail alerting.

How can I generate an array to be used as the `"customEmails"` property based on either a comma separated string, or an array type parameter?

I have tried `"customEmails": "[array(parameters('AlertEmailRecipients'))]"`, and also

```
"customEmails": [
    [array(parameters('AlertEmailRecipients'))]
]
```

but neither work. I don't know how to tell it that the "customEmails" property value should come from a parameter.

Comment: i dont understand the question, can you give an example? this should be fairly easy if you provide one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. The main problem was that my comma separated list of e-mail addresses had a space after each comma.

The way I have implemented it now is like this:

Define a string parameter with a comma separated list of e-mail addresses. *Don't have spaces in the list*.

Define a variable like this:

```
"customEmails" : "[split(parameters('AlertEmailRecipients'), ',')]"
```

and then reference that variable in the alerting action:

```
"action": {
    "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
    "sendToServiceOwners": false,
    "customEmails": "[variables('customEmails')]"
}
```

The [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-enable-alerts-using-template) actually does this, but doesn't make it clear the the list of e-mails can't contain spaces.

Comment: Revisiting this with a couple of years more experience with ARM templates. There is also a `replace` function which can be used to remove the extra spaces: `replace(parameters('AlertEmailRecipients'), ' ', '')`

Answer (score 14):

I used the following using an array parameter:

parameter declaration:

```
"customEmails": {
      "type": "array",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "alert email addressess"
      }
}
```

in the parameters file:

```
"customEmails": {
      "value": [
        "email1@domain.com",
        "email2@domain.com"     
      ]
    }
```

usage:

```
"customEmails": "[parameters('customEmails')]"
```