# Authorized IP Addresses for AKS using ARM Template

Tags: azure, arm, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy an AKS with authorized IP ranges enabled by default. I'm utilizing the following in my code:

```
parameters: {
 "AuthorizedIpRanges": {
   "type": "string",
   "default": "1.0.0.1,1.0.0.2,1.0.0.3"
 }
}
variables: {
 "authorizedIpRanges": "[split(parameters('AuthorizedIPRanges'),',')]"
}
properties: {
 "apiServerAccessProfile": {
   "authorizedIPRanges": "[variables('authorizedIpRanges')]"
 }
}
```

This deploys successfully, and I can see the Authorized IP Ranges checkbox checked in Portal, but there are no IP addresses listed.

I'm aware it takes an array of strings, but when I try to set the AuthorizedIpRanges type to "array" it is unable to process the json at all. Trying without the split gives "APIServerAccessProfile.properties.apiServerAccessProfile.authorizedIPRanges accept type []string, not type string"

I also do not have any spaces after the commas, as shown in the example above.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ARM template array parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453036/arm-template-array-parameter)

Comment: It does not, as my string array does not contain spaces.